# Efficient way to use newInstance method

Tags: android, android-fragments

What is the proper way of using newInstance method in Fragments. I have seen at most places where people are using  like

```
 public static MyFragment newInstance(int mData) {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("key", mData);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }
```

and then check again in fragment.

So why do I need to use bundle in the method, when I can directly use that value in one of the callback method in my fragment.

with this.mdata=mdata;
Is there a specific need to use it this way.???

Comment: Notice that the `newInstance()` method is `static`. To access a field from that method, that field would have to be `static`, as well.

Comment: Thank you @MikeM. , I am new to this forum,so is there a way to upvote answer...??? I found no option to do so.

Comment: Nah, it's just a comment. It's not really fleshed out enough to be a proper answer, IMO, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the `newInstance` pattern as an alternative to using constructors.  The android framework can re-instantiate your fragment at any time, and it does not invoke constructors with arguments.  For example, if you rotated the screen, `mData` would become `null`.  So in order to keep your `mData` around, it needs to be put in the bundle and retrieved from the bundle later (e.g., in `onCreate`).

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: Thank you @chessdork  for the response. I did go through many sites including this. But what I am not clear is that the data I am putting in bundle is from the parameter itself. So what if I am using a static variable . Apart from the fact that I create a static variable will it cause issues..??? or is it that since the fragments use empty constructors for recreation of fragments it utilizes data from Bundle only ...????

Comment: Right, the data you put in the bundle are the `newInstance` parameters.  If there are two parameters, then you should put two arguments in the Bundle.  In `onCreate`, you would have `mData = getArguments().getInt("data")`.  From there you can use it as a normal variable.